# Scala classOf on class with recursive type parameter

Tags: java, scala

I need to call `classOf` on a class written in Java as follows:

```
public class Order<I extends Item> {...}
```

where `Item` is like the following

```
public class Item<O extends Order> {...}
```

Then I need to pass the class of `Order` to some method. In Java, it is `Order.class`. But in Scala, I have to use `classOf(Order[Item[Order....)`.

What is the right way to get the `Order`'s class in Scala?

Comment: Nothing is clear from your `public class Order` and `public class Item`. Please provide more details about these classes

Comment: val orderClass = classOf[Order] should give Order class

Comment: @rags No, that won't work for parametrized types.

Answer (score 3):

How about simply `classOf[Order[_]]`?

(BTW, your Java declarations are using raw types — most likely, you'll need to declare things like `class Order<O extends Order<O, I>, I extends Item<O, I>>` and `class Item<O extends Order<O, I>, I extends Item<O, I>>`.)